# Will Genymotion connect to internet if networking drivers of Oracle Virtualbox are not installed?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, genymotion, genymotion-gps

Is it possible for Genymotion to work properly for testing my **apps which use internet**, *if I install the Oracle Virtual Box **without** its Networking drivers.*

Is there a way to make Genymotion directly use Internet from my computer only?

[image]

**Reason:** Because Oracle Virtual Box always messes up my *wifi* drivers, and I lose my wifi internet connection completely. I had tried every fix on the internet and nothing had helped, then I had to reinstall windows.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genymotion uses the Virtual Machine ( using the Oracle's Virtual Box). A virtual machine can get connected to the network only if you install the required drivers. So the simple answer is NO.

Try the Intel HAXM - [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager). Its an alternative to GenyMotion, but it provides less no. of features.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I wanted to use Genymotion for its speed, will this emulator be fast enough?

Comment: Yes it is based on the same technology ( hardware emulation). It is as fast as genymotion.